# Can't build CEDET for emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, cedet

Whenever I try to build CEDET with

```
emacs -Q -l cedet-build.el -f cedet-build
```

I get this status:

> CEDET BYTE COMPILATION STATUS:
>
> Step 1: Byte compile EIEIO...done
>
> Step 2: EDE Autloads...done.
>
> Step 3: Semantic Autloads...done.
>
> Step 4: SRecode Autloads...done.
>
> Step 5: Load common/cedet.el ...done
>
> Step 6: Turning on EDE ...

While step 6 I get following error in emacs:

> Invalid function: object-class-fast

What's wrong and what can I do about this?

Comment: Which version of CEDET?   Which version of Emacs?  Why not use the CEDET that is bundled with Emacs?

Comment: CEDET 1.1

Emacs 24.4.1

I installed emacs with apt-get and want to add CEDET now.

Comment: I guess CEDET 1.1 is not compatible with Emacs-24.4.  You can try contacting the CEDET people, or a more recent version of CEDET.  Or more simply just use the CEDET that is bundled with Emacs-24.4.